# Http Post request is not getting successful in angular js(1.5)

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I am working on HTTP post request in angular JS (1.5).

First I pass request data to factory method. Call the Http post request and send the response back to controller. But I always get the below error:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Below is my controller code:

```
app.controller("logicCtrl",['$scope','getDestinationService','getVehicleService','getTokenService','getResultService','$http', 
            function($scope, getDestinationService,getVehicleService,getTokenService,getResultService,$http){

        $scope.getResult = function(){

        var resultPromise = getResultService.getFinalResult($scope.request_data);

         resultPromise.then(function(result){
                $scope.result = result.data;
                console.log("result:"+$scope.result);
        });
      }
    });
```

And this is my factory method:

```
app.factory("getResultService",['$http','$q',function($http, $q){
    var getResultApi = "https://findfalcone.herokuapp.com/find";
    var headers = {'Accept' : 'application/json'};

    var getFinalResult = function(request_data){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var request_data = JSON.stringify(request_data);
        return $http({
        url: getResultApi,
        method: "POST",
        data: request_data,
        headers: {'Accept' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function (response) {
             if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                  deferred.resolve(response.data);
              } else {
                  deferred.reject(response.data);
              }
        }).catch(function(response) {
              return deferred.reject(response.data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }; 
    return { getFinalResult: getFinalResult };

}]);
```

**Edit: As some people are directly hitting the URL in browser and saying URL is not working. It won't work this way as it is post call, not get call. I tried testing this URL in Postman and it is working absolutely fine.
Here is the screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Have u tried to call that URL with post in postman or some other application to check if is working??

Comment: https://findfalcone.herokuapp.com/find this url not working

Comment: @pritesh yes URL is working fine. I edited the question and added screenshot too.

Comment: @RajaRamachandran It is working fine in postman. See the screenshot. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the `getFinalResult` you are overwriting the `Accept` header as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` where as it should be `application/json`. You are not using the headers variables declared earlier.

Disclaimer: I wrote the Finding Falcone backend application.